# IIS Rewrite / Redirect Rules Query

Tags: redirect, iis

The rule below does the following:
- http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
etc
- https://example.com/contacts.html -> . https://example.com/contacts
So (all requests to HTTPS, and all www -> (non)www) + hides .HTML extensions.

I would like to add the ability to remove the following issue:

https://example.com/Home.html ->  https://example.com/Home

But for the specific case of /Home I would prefer it displays  /

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Rule below:

```
            <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Force non-WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect .html extension" stopProcessing="false">
                    <match url="^(.*)\.html$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="hide .html extension" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some change in your rule to prevent rewrite for /Home and /. Then created two rules to handle request to /Home.html.

It works fine on my side and should achieve your requirement.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
              <rule name="Force non-WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect .html extension" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)\.html$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.html$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Home.html$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="hide .html extension" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Home$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="redirect /Home" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Home.html$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rewrite Home" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/Home.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```